# angular 2 component allowed input values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

I have one component for example

```
export class Foo {
@Input() myInput:string = 'a';

}
```

Now I want the allowed values of myInput to be any of these only: `a` , `b`, `c`, `d`

if someone tries to do

```
<foo myInput="x">
```

He should get an compilation error

I believe this is possible

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by

```
export class Foo {
@Input() myInput: ’a’ | ‘b’ | ‘c’ | ‘d’;

}
```

By doing this you are explicitly telling `TypeScript` to only allow those specific characters for the binding `myInput`

You can get a bit more detail on `type` guards and `type` definitions in the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)